Application of Schwarz-Pick lemma
I was stuck on this question: let $f$ be an analytic function from the unit disc to the upper half-plane. Prove that for any $w \in \Bbb D$(unit disc), $|f'(w)|\leq \frac{2\Im(f(w))}{1-|w|^2}$.
I tried to consider Cayley's transformation and constructed a composition function from the unit disc to the unit disc so that I could apply the Schwarz-Pick lemma here.
I feel I'm on the right track but somehow can't get the right answer. Any help would be appreciated!

$$
 g(w) = \frac{f(w)-i}{f(w)+i}
$$
maps the unit disk $\Bbb D$ into itself, so
$$
\frac{|g'(w)|}{1-|g(w)|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|w|^2}
$$
for all $w \in \Bbb D$ by the Schwarz-Pick theorem. Now
$$ \begin{align} 
\frac{|g'(w)|}{1-|g(w)|^2} &= \frac{2|f'(w)|}{|f(w)+i|^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\left| \frac{f(w)-i}{f(w)+i}\right|^2} \\
&= \frac{2|f'(w)|}{|f(w)+i|^2 - |f(w)-i|^2} \\
&= \frac{2|f'(w)|}{4 \operatorname{Im}f(w)}
\end{align} \, .
$$
Substituting that into the previous inequality gives
$$
\frac{|f'(w)|}{2 \operatorname{Im}f(w)} \le \frac{1}{1-|w|^2}
$$
which is the desired result.
